# Lower bound on $(1-x)^r$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

I am wondering is there a lower bound of the form $1-(1-o(1))rx$ on $(1-x)^r$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<r<1$, where $x\to 0$?

[Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) suggests that $(1-x)^r\ge 1-rx$ for $0<x<1$ and $r\ge 1$. I am wondering what happens to $0<r<1$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $1-x\ge e^{-\frac{x}{1-x}}$ for $0<x<1$ and $\frac{1}{1-x}\le 1+2x$ for $x>0$ small enough. Therefore
$$(1-x)^r\ge e^{-\frac{x}{1-x}r}\ge (1-\frac{x}{1-x}r)\ge (1-x(1+2x)r)=(1-(1+o(1))rx).$$

Comment: How is $2x = o(1)$?